# Server-side software for translating languages?

Tags: translation, nlp, server-side, machine-translation

I am searching for a server-side application (not a service, we need to host this ourselves) that can take a given string and translate it to another language. Open-source, paid, doesn't matter.

Can anyone provide some recommendations?

Comment: Which source language(s) to which target language(s)?

Comment: English -> ... Whatever is available. Spanish, French, Chinese, Swedish, etc... I work with projects that have involved dozens of different languages.

Comment: Any reason why you don't just maintain languages files with all the strings pre-translated?

Comment: We are translating live data that is supplied by users of the application.

Comment: shopping recommendations are not on topic http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Answer (score 3):

**Open Source Translation Packages**

Here are some state-of-the-art open-source machine translation packages:

- [cdec (C++)](http://cdec-decoder.org/index.php?title=Main_Page)
- [Joshua (Java)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/joshua/)
- [Moses (C++)](http://www.statmt.org/moses/)
- [Phrasal (Java) - soon to be released](http://nlp.stanford.edu/phrasal/)

**Training Data**

To use each of the packages above, you'll need training data. If you're translating between many European languages you can use Phillip Koehn's [Europarl parallel corpus](http://www.statmt.org/europarl/). If you're interested in a European Union (EU) language that's not in the Europarl parallel corpus, you can gather the data by crawling the [proceedings of the European parliament](http://www.europarl.europa.eu/omk/omnsapir.so/calendar?APP=CRE&LANGUE=EN). All the EU proceedings are translated into each of the EU languages and made available for free online, which makes them a very good source of machine translation training data.

You can get training data for non-European languages from the [Linguistics Data Consortium (LDC)](http://www.ldc.upenn.edu) catalog (e.g., [Chinese-to-English](http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/Catalog/CatalogEntry.jsp?catalogId=LDC2007T09)).